# Не возращается объект из функции

Tags: javascript, node.js

Почитал [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/150788/) по асинхронную архитектуру, решил передалать свой вариант

```
var User = require(__dirname + '/../models/User.js');
var foundUser = User.findOne(id); //тут я получаю объект
```

на правильный типа

```
User.findOne(id, function(err, id) {...} //тут undefined
```

Класс User

```
exports.findOne = function (id) {
  ...
  return foundUser; //тут нахожу объект и отдаю
}
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: Ну так вы же в реализации `findUser` не принимаете функцию обратного вызова в качестве аргумента... Какого еще результата вы ждете?

Comment: Вы не могли бы с примером, я в js не силен, изучаю и фразу "принимать функцию обратного вызова в качестве обратного аргумента" не очень понимаю.